# Android: Read/Send text messages on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, sms, adb

As an android programmer I spend an awful lot of time with my test device (phone) plugged into my computer. And being as lazy as I am, I would like to be able to send texts via my computer through my phone.

For example:
   I get a text, The text is pushed to the active ADB connection from which I can send it to a running script that will allow me to see the text on my computer. I can then type the response, hit enter, which will push the text through the active ADB connection, to the phone and be sent to the target.

Is there any way I do this?  Maybe there is an ADB command that I can route through a python script or something?

Comment: @harper89 Who can be anything but? :)

Comment: I am lazily awaiting an answer.

Comment: I discovered that I can email a text to someone. Didn't know that was allowed. So I got an idea on how to respond, I just need a way to pull recent incoming texts and the associated numbers.

Comment: Have you heard about MyPhone Explorer I think this is what you needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend SL4A scripting layer. You can connect to SL4A hosted server via adb or tcp/ip, and then execute script to send SMS. Among several script language supported by SL4A, I think python API is most mature and useful.

SL4A Remote Control:

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/RemoteControl

SL4A SMS API:

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference#smsSend

Comment: Looks like something I want to mess with later.

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look at that now. I looks like it should be solid, if I can get it to work :)

Comment: @shr - You are my hero. I can't believe I never found this before?! This thing is fantastic and just what I was looking for! You have just solved a number of projects I have been wanting to do!

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
adb shell am start -S -e sms_body 'your message body' \
      -e address receiver -t 'vnd.android-dir/mms-sms' \
      com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity \
      && adb shell input keyevent 66

Explainations:
    -S: force stop the target app before starting the activity
    -e sms_body 'your message body': add extra key-value data 
            as sms_body=>'sms body'
    -e address phone-number: similar to the above
    -t vnd.android-dir/mms-sms: MIME type
    com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity: 
            target pkg/activity component
    adb shell input keyevent 66: finally hit the enter key
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gmail for this, on the chat widget in your gmail page, mouse over the contact you want to sms. Click the more button and you will see a send sms option. If you don't already have a phone number for that contact it will prompt you to enter a phone number. I just added myself to my contacts  in gmail to send myself texts.

Comment: Thanks for the response and you're absolutely correct, however, I was looking for a more... programmatic solution. Something I can use with out an internet connection? With this solution I must rely on GMail. I just want some little script running in one of my desktops.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA Ahh so a fake text message?  You could send your own broadcast with a 'fake' text message. Some SMS apps like the system one are smart enough to know that the broadcast isn't from the system package and will ignore it. But depending on what your goal is this may be the right solution for you..

Comment: Not quite text message faking. Let me try to explain. I'll be working on something with my phone plugged into my computer. When I get a text, I want my computer to be notified and post the text on some sort of medium. Then I will be able to type a reply, and forward my reply to me phone for my reply to be sent.